# CSS transitions not working Firefox for XML document transformed to HTML with XSLT

Tags: css, firefox, xslt, css-transitions

I have a fairly complex XML document referencing an XSTL document to transform it into something more visually pleasing / informative.

This is not a huge issue, but it bugs me that css transitions aren't applied in Firefox. Copy the generated html code from the developer tools into a plain .html file and css transitions works as expected.

Any ideas on how to force Firefox to apply modern css features to documents rendered from xml with xslt?

Here is a minimal case that reproduces the trouble:
http://www.developer-b.com/trouble/xsl/data.xml
http://www.developer-b.com/trouble/xsl/data.xsl
http://www.developer-b.com/trouble/xsl/data.html (copy of html generated by Firefox)

Comment: Do you have some code to share? Post a URL where we can reproduce the problem or insert minimal but complete code samples to allow us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Sure, I've updated my question with some links

Comment: It looks like a bug in Mozilla to me, as you have a test case you could file the bug on https://bugzilla.mozilla.org.

Comment: Thanks! I'm starting to think the same thing. I'll file a bug report.

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1135764

Comment: I think the problem is fixed now in Firefox 37.

Comment: Lovely! Thanks for your help. If you post that as an answer I can accept it when I get my hands on Firefox 37 and can confirm it.  Btw, I'm impressed by how professionally Mozilla handles bug requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we established, it was indeed [a bug in Firefox/Gecko](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1135764) which has been fixed now in Firefox 37. The test case https://bug1135764.bugzilla.mozilla.org/attachment.cgi?id=8568458 works fine for me with Firefox 37 on both Windows as well as Android, on hovering over the red box there is an animated transition of the rotation to 20 degrees.